# When did C# get this "SFINAE-like" overload resolution of Action<..> parameters, and what is it called?

Tags: c#, syntax, overloading, type-inference, type-systems

Consider the following code, where C# can disambiguate the overload based on the *implicitly typed Action<T>* that is supplied, where T is derived based *on the [mutually exclusive] type-validity of the action's code*.

I was pleasantly surprised, realizing that I've been "relying on this convenient behavior without thought" for awhile, even though it requires that the compiler examines the code inside the Action as well as the valid target site types. Normally the type has to be resolved *before* it is used in the target expression.

When was this behavior introduced? What is the proper name for this type inference? What are some limitations and known edge-cases? And what documentation link (or section in specification) covers the behavior?

```
static void WithAction(Action<string> s) {
    Console.WriteLine("string action");
    s("string");
}

static void WithAction(Action<int> i) {
    Console.WriteLine("int action");
    i(1);
}

void Main()
{
    // Compiler has to INFER that this is an Action<string>
    // where the target type must be in {Action<string>, Action<int>}
    // (int does not have a Length property)
    WithAction(s => Console.WriteLine(s.Length == 1));

    // Ditto, except compiler infers Action<int>.
    // (there is no string == int operator overload)
    WithAction(i => Console.WriteLine(i == 1));

    // compiler error
    // CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
    // 'UserQuery.WithAction(Action<string>)' and 'UserQuery.WithAction(Action<int>)'
    // (there is both int == int and string == string!)
    // WithAction(z => Console.WriteLine(z == z));
}
```

The code runs in LINQPad 5 and produces the following output:

```
string action
False
int action
True
```

Comment: Jon Skeet has written a great blog post that might help point you towards some of your answers: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/

Comment: @DavidL Thanks for the link. However, it doesn't appear to cover this case. In the above, it's not decided between eg. `Action<T>` (more specific) and `Action`, it's deciding between `Action<string>` and `Action<int>`, where the actions have to be "attempted to be compiled" as the target type to see if they _can_ match one _XOR_ the other overloaded methods. I've included the non-compiling case, when the body of the method is _not_ sufficient for the compiler to reason that the parameter to the Action is `string` *XOR* `int` (and thus the Action must be `Action<string>` or `Action<int>`).

Answer (score 2):

The C# spec covers this in [Anonymous Function Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#anonymous-function-conversions).

Anonymous functions include lambda expressions that old `delegate (...) { ... }` syntax.

In that section, it says that an anonymous function `F` can be converted to a delegate type `D` provided:

> If the body of `F` is an expression, and either `D` has a `void` return type or `F` is `async` and `D` has the return type `Task`, then when each parameter of `F` is given the type of the corresponding parameter in `D`, the body of `F` is a valid expression (wrt [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions)) that would be permitted as a statement_expression.

Essentially, the point is that the conversion is only valid when "the body of `F` is a valid (statement) expression". If `s` is `int`, `Console.WriteLine(s.Length == 1)` is not a valid statement expression, so there is no conversion.

When the compiler considers applicable function members during overload resolution, the overload taking `Action<int>` is simply not considered because there is no (implicit) conversion to `Action<int>`.

Judging from the fact that this applies to all anonymous functions, this feature *probably* isn't new. It might be as old as `delegate (...) { ... }`.

Comment: And I "just recently" realized something special was going on. I care not say how long I've been using C#. ^_^